# Change the tag for equations

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

I want to show my equations in the form (Eq. 1) instead of (1).

I am trying using `\tag` but this changes completely.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: How should the equation numbers appear in cross-references: as `(Eq. n)`, or as `(n)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand\theequation{Eq.~\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
a^2+b^2=c^2 
\end{equation}
A cross-reference to equation~(\ref{eq:1}).
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the word "equation" in the sentence "A cross-reference to equation (Eq. 1)" maybe redundant?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `mathtools` package and define `tagforms`, i.e. the formatting of the equation tag. The `\usetagform` is a switch to a new formatting of the tag, and you can have several. It is better in that case to use the `cleveref` package for the cross-references, as the default `\eqref` uses the formatting of the last `\usetagform` that appears outside of a group, which may not be wanted:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newtagform{Eq}[\upshape]{(\text{Eq. }}{)}
\usetagform{Eq}
\newtagform{coloured}[\color{red}{[}]{}{]}

\begin{document}
Some stuff ...

\begin{equation}\label{silly}
 a = b + c
\end{equation}
As one can see in \cref{silly}, i. e.  in \eqref{silly}…
\usetagform{coloured}
\begin{equation}
\label{oomph}
 a²  = b²  + c²
\end{equation}
 or in \cref{oomph}, i. e.  in  \eqref{oomph}

\begin{equation}
\usetagform{default}
\label{grump}
 a³   = b³   + c³ 
\end{equation}
 or in \cref{grump}, i. e.  in  \eqref{grump}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I forgot to say that you can change `tag form` only locally, i.e. have different types of equations with different tag forms.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `\tagform@` macro of the `amsmath` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter % make "@" a letter-type symbol
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{(Eq.~#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}
\makeatother
\setlength\textwidth{2.5in} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
a^2+b^2=c^2 
\end{equation}
A cross-reference to equation (\ref{eq:1}).
\end{document}
```